# Detect if Stored Proc is being called within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions

Ok - so the answer is probably 'everything is within a transaction in SQLServer'. But here's my problem.

I have a stored procedure which returns data based on one input parameter. This is being called from an external service which I believe is Java-based.

I have a log-table to see how long each hit to this proc is taking. Kind of like this (simplified)...

```
TABLE log (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Param VARCHAR(10), In DATETIME, Out DATETIME)

PROC troublesome
(@param VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    --log the 'in' time and keep the ID
    DECLARE @logid INT
    INSERT log (In,Param) VALUES (GET_DATE(),@param)
    SET @logid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT <some stuff from another table based on @param>

    --set the 'out' time
    UPDATE log SET Out = GET_DATE() WHERE ID = @logid

END
```

So far so easily-criticised by SQL fascists.

Anyway - When I call this eg `troublesome 'SOMEPARAM'` - I get the result of the `SELECT` back and in the log table is a nice new row with the `SOMEPARAM` and the in and out timestamps.

Now - I watch this table, and even though no rows are going in - if *I* am to generate a row, I will see that the ID has skipped many places. I guess this is being caused by the external client code hitting it. They are getting the result of the `SELECT` - but I am not getting their log data.

This suggests to me they are wrapping their client call in a `TRAN` and rolling it back. Which is *one* thing that would cause this behaviour. I want to know...

- If there is a way I can FORCE the write of the log even if it is contained within a transaction over which I have no control and which is subsequently rolled back (seems unlikely)
- If there is a way I can determine from within this proc if it is executing within a transaction (and perhaps raise an error)
- If there are other possible explanations for the ID skipping (and it's skipping *alot* like 1000 places in an hour. So I'm *sure* it's caused by the client code - as they are reporting successfully retrieving the results of the `SELECT` also.)

Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStarostin I thought this but I wasn't sure if it would work. I shall do an experiment. Do you know if this will work even if they are calling from non-MS environment?

Comment: I just reviewed your code - is this proc called from catch-block?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Well, this is one of the things. I can't see the client code as it's in production from another application developed by an entirely different team. It is called from a Java application I believe but I'm not sure whether the call is within a Java Try..Catch - What is your idea?

Comment: My idea was about having lots of rollbacks (gaps of 1000 numbers and transaction question). If this is a "technical" logging/audit proc you may try to implement it with C# with option which says "run this in separate connection". So even if whole transaction was rolled back, changes done by audit SP will persist.

Answer (score 1):

For the why rows are skipped part of the question, your assumption sounds plausible to me.

For how to force the write even within a transaction, I don't know.

As for how to discover whether the SP is running inside a transaction how about the following:

```
SELECT @@trancount
```

I tested this out in an sql batch and seems to be ok. Maybe it can take you a bit further.